# What are the bundling/naming conventions for source-based packages?

Tags: linux, libraries, coding-standards

Are there any conventions to use if I were to distribute the source for a C++ library I built? The plan is to use CMake as a build system, but for the rest I was wondering what are the standards in terms of file/folder/subfolder naming, inclusion paths etc.

What I got so far:

- Put everything in the `$prefix` folder under `$prefix/bin`, `$prefix/include/libname` and `$prefix/lib`.
- Don't use caps for libname.

Should all internal includes contain the `libname` folder? E.g. say there are two files in the project: `principal.h` and `secondary.h`.

In `principal.h`, should the inclusion statement for `secondary` be : `#include "secondary.h"` or `#include "libname/secondary.h"`?

Are there other standards that should be followed? Why?

Answer (score 2):

You could do worse than following [chapter 7](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Managing-Releases.html#Managing-Releases) of the GNU Coding Standards. It pretty much just distills standard practice.

You're welcome to disagree with any of it, of course. It's enough that you think through the issues and know *why* you're disagreeing.